# Number of predicted POS tags is not matched with the word sequence in Bi-LSTM model

Tags: python, tensorflow, bilstm

I have trained a POS tagger using Bi-LSTM. Here I attached the code that was used to train the model.

```
    # Load files containing word sequence and tag sequence  
with codecs.open('news_verified_train_words_adj_adverb.txt','r',encoding='utf-8') as f1:
    train_data = f1.readlines()
    
with codecs.open('news_verified_train_tags_adj_adverb.txt','r',encoding='utf-8') as f2:
    train_tags = f2.readlines()
```

news_verified_train_words_adj_adverb contains the word sequences separated by a new line (each line contains simply a sentence) and news_verified_train_tags_adj_adverb contains the corresponding part of speech tag sequence for each sentence (each line contains simply a tag sequence).

```
X = [] #2d list contains sentences, inner list holds words of each sentence
Y = [] #2d list contains tag sequence for each sentence, inner list holds tags

for i in range (len(train_data)):
    sentence = []
    tag_sequence = []
    sentence_splitted = train_data[i].strip().split()
    tag_sequence_splitted = train_tags[i].strip().split()
    
    for j in range (len(sentence_splitted)):
        sentence.append(sentence_splitted[j])
        tag_sequence.append(tag_sequence_splitted[j])
        
    X.append(sentence)
    Y.append(tag_sequence)



# encode X

word_tokenizer = Tokenizer()                      # instantiate tokeniser
word_tokenizer.fit_on_texts(X)                    # fit tokeniser on data
X_encoded = word_tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X)  # use the tokeniser to encode input sequence

# encode Y

tag_tokenizer = Tokenizer()
tag_tokenizer.fit_on_texts(Y)
Y_encoded = tag_tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(Y)

# Pad each sequence to MAX_SEQ_LENGTH using KERAS' pad_sequences() function. 
# Sentences longer than MAX_SEQ_LENGTH are truncated.
# Sentences shorter than MAX_SEQ_LENGTH are padded with zeroes.

# Truncation and padding can either be 'pre' or 'post'. 
# For padding we are using 'pre' padding type, that is, add zeroes on the left side.
# For truncation, we are using 'post', that is, truncate a sentence from right side.

MAX_SEQ_LENGTH = 300  # sequences greater than 200 in length will be truncated

X_padded = pad_sequences(X_encoded, maxlen=MAX_SEQ_LENGTH, padding="pre", truncating="post")
Y_padded = pad_sequences(Y_encoded, maxlen=MAX_SEQ_LENGTH, padding="pre", truncating="post")

# assign padded sequences to X and Y
X, Y = X_padded, Y_padded

# load fastText word vectors using the following function present in the gensim library
fastTextWordVectors = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('cc.si.300.vec')
 
# assign word vectors from word2vec model

EMBEDDING_SIZE  = 300  # each word in word2vec model is represented using a 300 dimensional vector
VOCABULARY_SIZE = len(word_tokenizer.word_index) + 1

# create an empty embedding matix
embedding_weights = np.zeros((VOCABULARY_SIZE, EMBEDDING_SIZE))

# create a word to index dictionary mapping
word2id = word_tokenizer.word_index

# copy vectors from word2vec model to the words present in corpus
for word, index in word2id.items():
    try:
        embedding_weights[index, :] = fastTextWordVectors[word]
    except KeyError:
        pass

# use Keras' to_categorical function to one-hot encode Y
Y = to_categorical(Y,dtype="int32")

# split entire data into training and testing sets
TEST_SIZE = 0.15
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=TEST_SIZE, random_state=4)

# split training data into training and validation sets
VALID_SIZE = 0.15
X_train, X_validation, Y_train, Y_validation = train_test_split(X_train, Y_train, test_size=VALID_SIZE, random_state=4)

# total number of tags
NUM_CLASSES = Y.shape[2]
print(NUM_CLASSES)


 # create architecture
bidirect_model_adj_adv = Sequential()
bidirect_model_adj_adv.add(Embedding(input_dim = VOCABULARY_SIZE,
 output_dim = EMBEDDING_SIZE,
 input_length = MAX_SEQ_LENGTH,
 weights = [embedding_weights],
 trainable = True
))
bidirect_model_adj_adv.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True)))
bidirect_model_adj_adv.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(NUM_CLASSES, activation='softmax')))
#compile model
bidirect_model_adj_adv.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['acc'])
# check summary of model
bidirect_model_adj_adv.summary()

bidirect_adj_adv_training = bidirect_model_adj_adv.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=40, validation_data=(X_validation, Y_validation))
```

When predicting using the trained model, for some input word sequences the predicted pos tag sequence is not matched. here I attached the code sample used to test that.

```
predicted_results = bidirect_model_adj_adv.predict(X_test)
category_meaning_pr = np.argmax(predicted_results, axis=-1)

#predicted tags
predicted_tags = tag_tokenizer.sequences_to_texts(category_meaning_pr)

category_meaning_at = np.argmax(Y_test, axis=-1)
#actual tags
actual_tags = tag_tokenizer.sequences_to_texts(category_meaning_at)

not_matching = []

for i in range(len(actual_tags)):
    actual_tags_per_item = actual_tags[i].split()
    predicted_tags_per_item = predicted_tags[i].split()
    if len(actual_tags_per_item) != len(predicted_tags_per_item):
        print(i)
        not_matching.append(i)
```

If there are any elements appended in the not_matching list, for those word sequences, number of predicted tags is not same as the number of the word sequence. In my scenario, I got a few elements appended in not_matching list. What is the reason for that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "the predicted pos tag sequence is not matched." I have no idea what that means. I can't run your code and reproduce the error you report. Please offer some code that clarifies what the expected and actual behavior is. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @J_H I modifed the question with full code